# SSO Linux and AD Trusted Domain

Tags: linux, active-directory, pam, single-sign-on, sssd

Having successfully built a one-way trust between 2 AD domains, we can't lookup/id the user in the trusted domain.

Here's our use case.

- AD1: dom1.com (Win2k8 R2) - One-way outgoing trust to AD2
- AD2: dom2.com (Win2kr R2) - One-way incoming trust from AD1
- Linux1: member of AD1/dom1.com
- Can lookup User1: Linux1>$id AD1\User1 - OK
- Can't lookup User2 Linux1>$id AD2\User2 - Not OK.
- PAM and SSSD are working fine within AD1 domain.

I tried adding a domain entry in sssd.conf (eg. [domain/AD2]) but didn't help at all. Kerberos is working fine as per successful lookup of User1.

Appreciate your inputs to solve our issue.

/etc/sssd/sssd.conf

```
[sssd]    
config_file_version = 2  
debug_level = 0  
domains = dom1.com, dom2.com  
services = nss, pam  

[domain/dom1.com]  
id_provider = ad  
access_provider = simple  
simple_allow_groups = user_group  
ldap_id_mapping = false  
enumerate = true  

[domain/dom2.com]  
id_provider = ad  
auth_provider = ad  
chpass_provider = ad  
access_provider = simple  
simple_allow_groups = user_group  
ldap_id_mapping = false  
enumerate = true
```

Comment: Can you please show your `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` file?

Comment: No takers yet? Any leads direct or indirect hit would be appreciated.

Comment: I've heard that you can accomplish SSO, using kerberos, maybe that's the way to go...